# json format from rails to sproutcore

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, sproutcore

For those of you using Rails as a backend to their Sproutcore clients,
which one is the best way to format the data into json?

From the Sproutcore guides there was this approach:

```
 def as_json(options = {})
   event_hash = {
     "guid" => self.id,
     "id" => self.id,
     "designation" => self.designation,
     "category" => self.category,
     "scheduled_for" => self.scheduled_for,
     "location" => self.location,
     "groups" => self.groups,
     "resources" => self.resources
   }

   event_hash
 end
```

But it fails, send an "Illegal statement error". Then, I changed to this other method:

```
 def as_json(options = {})
   # event_hash = options.merge(:include => [:groups, :resources], :methods => :guid)
   event_hash = options.merge(:methods => :guid)
   super(event_hash)
 end
```

which seems to be working as far as the formatting is concerned, although I am suspecting it to causing some trouble regarding the representation in the dataHash of the store. Anyway, ha anyone been having similar issues with the first version of as_json? If not, is there anything I am doing wrong?

Appreciate any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the first method you need to call super:

```
def as_json(options = {})
  event_hash = {
    "guid" => self.id,
    "id" => self.id,
    "designation" => self.designation,
    "category" => self.category,
    "scheduled_for" => self.scheduled_for,
    "location" => self.location,
    "groups" => self.groups,
    "resources" => self.resources
  }

  super(event_hash)
end
```

However you should get the options param and process to do this apropiately.

Comment: That `super()` call is the biggest difference between the two the original poster lists, so I think this is on the right track.

Comment: could you please elaborate more on processing the options params? I added the call to super and it works without raising an exception. However, I only get one record sent to the sproutcore. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: You should use the `options` that you use as a parameter and merge with default options for example.